# How to access file of previous directory in web pages?

Tags: html, directory-structure

I have one of my webpage in a folder but want to access url outside this folder .How can I do this?I know its a very basic question but I don't know the solution.So pls help!!
my webpage x/folder/index.html
I want to access :x/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts there (and so on...)
To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep moving forward

Answer (score 0):

You can access files outside your current directory with relative paths. Try using `..` to move up a directory.

For example, If you are in `x/folder/index.html` and you can use the path `../index.html` to get `x/index.html'